# jquery - do a click immediately on mousedown or touch

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer, touch

I have a 42" touchdisplay showing a webpage with IE9.

There are a lot of anchors on it. Sometimes a user does not just shortly taps a link but stays on it and nothing happens until he stops touching.

As a first solution I showed the user a message that he should take his finger of the touchpad.

```
        var timeoutLongTouch;
        $(".long-touch").on('mousedown.LongTouch', function () {
            timeoutLongTouch = setTimeout(function () {
                $("#warning").show();
            }, 1000);
        })
        .on('mouseup.LongTouch', function () {
            clearTimeout(timeoutLongTouch);
            $("#warning").hide();
        });
```

This works fine. But now I'd prefer to change the longtouch event to an immediatly fired click.

I tried several ways - f.e.

```
    $(".long-touch").on('mousedown.LongTouch', function () {
        var item = $(this);
        setTimeout( function () {
            console.log(item);
            $(item).click();
        }, 300);
    });
```

But whatever I tried click is not fired until user takes his finger of.

Is there a way to convert the longtouch into a immiediate click when user touches a link, not depending of the duration of the topuch?

Comment: Sounds like you want to use the `touchstart` event

Answer (score 0):

Could you try to use the following?

```
$('.long-touch').on('touchstart click', function(event){
    event.stopPropagation();
    event.preventDefault();

   //do your stuff
});
```

For touch you need to use the touchstart, and we also listen to the click for normal desktop users.

Comment: No - this does not help. When I add my $(item).click(); after releasing the mouse or touch this is run endlessly in a loop. Which actually shows me that click is fired. But it still happens only _after_ the release.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution.
The idea of @Dirk-Jan together with not triggering a click, but simply refer to href location does it.

```
    $('.long-touch').on('mousedown.LongTouch touchstart click', function(event){
        event.stopPropagation();
        event.preventDefault();
        var item = $(this);
        setTimeout( function () {
            var dest = item.attr('href');
            window.location.href = dest;
        }, 300);
    });
```